# How to improve multicast in AP

Tags: wireless-access-point, multicast

I have more than 10 clients are connecting to that AP, pinging 30000 size packet.
After 1 -2 hours, start to see 1-2 devices encountered tx-ccq low% (eg. 1 - 5%).

Is this issue related with multicast ? If yes, any idea to improve the multicast performance in this AP?

Comment: You're using ping to send a 30,000 *byte* ICMP Echo datagram? So, it's getting IP-fragmented into about 20 full-size frames given typical Ethernet and Wi-Fi MTUs of 1500 bytes? Was this intentional? If you want to ping with a single full-size frame, use `ping -s 1472 …`.

Comment: Hi Spiff. I intended to do that. This is to simulate the case if I transmitting video using my AP to those clients.

Answer (score 0):

Multicast and broadcast will use the lowest connection speed available on a WAP, and this can impact performance of other applications. You could try to configure the WAP to increase the lowest available connection speed, but that may decrease the distance for which it works, and the devices which can connect to it.

Also, you may be hitting the limit of the WAP for the number of users with which it can comfortably work. Even high-end enterprise WAPs will struggle with more than 20 or 30 users.

Comment: Thanks for the replied! What about I do it as unicast, since my station no need to talk to each other.

Comment: is multiple unicast = multicast?

Comment: @Jess: No, multiple unicast is still unicast; it doesn't become multicast unless it's a single packet sent to a special 'group' address. That said, in many APs, there's an option for the AP to convert the multicast packet into multiple unicast packets, one for each recipient (each of which can be delivered at a much higher speed than the original multicast one). I've seen it labelled "multicast-to-unicast" and "multicast optimization" in other places.

Comment: thanks. In my case, I think it is multiple unicast, which is =unicast. So I should disable multicast option in my AP, am I right? Previously I had enable multicast enhancement in my AP.